# Firebase A/B testing - first_open event missing on Activation event

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I am creating an A/B testing in firebase but I am missing the default parameters from firebase in *Targeting* step -> *Activation event*.

When I navigate to *"Events"* I do see `first_open` event, but that event its not listed under *"Activation event"* list.

Why are some events missing?

My experiment should only be based on `first_open`, as the test is related to onboarding flow (only for new users).

Comment: hey there! Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @JEL not really. I had to create my own custom event as activation event.

Comment: Thank you for answering! That helps to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use an activation event that occurs or happens before the fetch > activate or fetchAndActivate. Please note that activation events should be triggered after these methods on Remote Config to make sure that the app instance (user) will be included in the experiment.